# Need help on module import :flask

Tags: visual-studio-code, flask, module, python-3.11

I use VScode to code with python,and I am really a beginner.
I install flask using pip into the 'scripts' directory and add the path to VScode through python.autoComplete.extraPaths.
Then the interpreter can figure out the module flask as in the first picture
But after running the program I still get Modulenotfounderror
I just dont know why and needy for help ><
[My codes,you can see that flask is figured out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brIaJ.png)
[I still got error oops](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py1u0.png)

Just someone that can tell me what is going wrong.TAT

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed flask in the virtual environment? If yes you will need to activate the venv on the terminal session you're trying to run the script.

Comment: I am really thankful for ur reply.Well actually I choose the wrong interpreter for VS code.(For I once struggled with poetry -_-) So actually my question is done,but I would like to thank you for respond to my question so quickly. ^o^